# matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch: does not get called to invited player?

Tags: game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I am working on a multiplayer game using Game Kit.  "auto match" is working great, but not "invite friend."  The problem is that matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch: is not getting called on the invited player's device.  Is there some other delegate method that I'm not seeing, which I should be using for the invitee?

I noticed in the apple docs, talking about this method, it says this:

> This method is called when the view controller’s hosted property is
>   NO.

Is this hosted property referring to the hosting device, or that the game is hosted on a server?

Comment: The hosted property is something you set on the MatchmakerViewController prior to presenting it.  You set it to "YES" when you are using hosted matches.

Comment: Also, I am having the exact same problem (with a hosted match).  As far as I can tell, hosted matchmaking with invites is completely broken; there is no way to construct a match with both invited players and auto-matched players.